# Magento 2 Add New Category Description

Tags: magento2.3, category, adminhtml, uicomponent

I built a simple module to create another field for the category description.  But I get an error:

```
The attribute with a "added_category_description" attributeCode doesn't exist. Verify the attribute and try again.
```

In etc/module.xml:

```
 <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.3" schema_version="1.0.3">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
```

in vendor/module/Setup/InstallData:

```
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
 
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
 
    private $eavSetupFactory;
 
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
 
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
 
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'added_category_description',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Added Description',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 4,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

in adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="added_category_description" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="60" formElement="wysiwyg">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Added Category Description</label>
                <dataScope>added_category_description</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
                    <settings>
                        <rows>8</rows>
                        <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                    </settings>
                </wysiwyg>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

in frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="added.category.description" template="Vendor_Module::product/list/added_category_description.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and finally in frontend/templates/product/list/added_category_description.phtml:

```
<?php if ($_addedCategoryDescription = $block->getCurrentCategory()->getAddedCategoryDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-added-category-description">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($block->getCurrentCategory(), $_addedCategoryDescription, 'added_category_description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I install the module, run upgrade, compile, deploy content, clear/flush cache, reindex and I get that error:

```
The attribute with a "added_category_description" attributeCode doesn't exist. Verify the attribute and try again.
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Stan

Comment: I had mentioned I already did that so that isn't it.  Anyone have other thoughts other than running commands I have already run?

Comment: check in ```eav_attribute``` table if attribute exists

Comment: @SebastianT Thanks for the tip!  No, it isn't in there.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try this: remove your module record from ```setup_module``` table. then run setup:upgrade again. This will install your module again. Maybe you create module, install it and then you create ```InstallData``` file. InstallData file run only onece when you install module. After upgrade check if your module is enable (php bin/magento module:status)

Comment: I also have in ```install``` method at the beginning: ```$setup->startSetup();``` and at the end ```$setup->endSetup();```. Try to add this, remove from ```setup_module``` and install again. And let me know if this help you .

Comment: @SebastianT Thanks Sebastian, that got it working.

Comment: Glad i could help :) I've added answer with working script for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**InstalData.php**

```
<?php
 
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;
 
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
 
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
 
    /**
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
 
    /**
     * Installs data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
 
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
           
            'category_delivery_description',
            [
                'type'         => 'text',
                'label'        => 'Delivery Description',
                'input'        => 'textarea',
                'sort_order'   => '',
                'source'       => '',
                'global'       => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible'      => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default'      => null,
                'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'group'        => '',
                'backend'      => ''
            ]
        );
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

This is working script to add category attribute. After running this script attribute should show in `eav_attribute`  table.
Also you have to remember that **InstallData.php** run only once. When you install your module, when you run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. If you create your module, run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then you want to add custom attribute, you have to delete record realated to your module from DB, from `setup_module` table .
If you want to add another custom attribute after some time you can use **UpgradeData.php** ([Helpful link](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-how-to-create-sql-setup-script.html))